# How to increase the value of multiple fields on one (+/-)click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Based on the article "How to increase the value of a quantity field" I tried to find a way how I can get an action on multiple fields with one click on the +/-button.

What i like to get as an result is: When I click on the (+)button the one field will be increased by 1 and in the same moment the field "bestand1" will be decreased by one - and also the other way round: Increasing the one causes decreasing the other in the same moment.

Here is what I tried based on the other article:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $(".add").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).next(".qty").val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt($(this).next(".bestand").val());

        if (currentVal >= 10)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal = 10);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal < 10)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
            $(this).next(".bestand").val(bestandVal - 1);
        }  
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".qty").val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".bestand").val());

        if (currentVal <= 0)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal = 0);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal > 0)
        {
            $(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
            $(this).prev(".bestand").val(bestandVal - 1);
        }

    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="myform">
        bestand1
        <input type="text" id="bestand1" value="20" class="bestand" disabled /><br /><br />
        bestand2
        <input type="text" id="bestand2" value="20" class="bestand" disabled /><br /><br />
        product1
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="add" />        
        <input type="text" id="qty1" value="2" class="qty" disabled/>        
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" /><br /><br />

        product2
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add2" class="add" />        
        <input type="text" id="qty2" value="2" class="qty" disabled/>        
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus2" class="minus" />

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: It seems you arent linking the product1 to bestand1, and product2 to bestand2... You want product1 increase to decrease bestand1, and the other way around right?

Comment: I began to look at your script, but I found many flaws and weird coding. I've done some editing to the `add`-functunality, but it does not work. My FF crashed and I can't use firebug, but you could take a look at how I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/vDGt6/

Comment: yes right! Hope i can discribe it a little better: if you click on the (+)-button of (for example) product1 the amount of bestand1 should be decreased by one.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: I looked at your example but there the + / - buttons do causes no actions on any field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is, assuming you keep add1 and minus1 linked to qty1 and bestand1, and 2...etc

```
$(function()
{
    $(".add").click(function()
    {
        // get id number of the calling elememnt
        var num = parseInt(this.id.substr(3));

        // get jquery elements
        var el_qty = $("#qty"+num);
        var el_bes = $("#bestand"+num);

        // get current values
        var currentVal = parseInt(el_qty.val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt(el_bes.val());

        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal < 10)
        {
            // increment values
            el_qty.val(++currentVal);
            el_bes.val(--bestandVal);
        }
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        // get id number of the calling elememnt
        var num = parseInt(this.id.substr(5));

        // get jquery elements
        var el_qty = $("#qty"+num);
        var el_bes = $("#bestand"+num);

        // get current values
        var currentVal = parseInt(el_qty.val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt(el_bes.val());

        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal > 0)
        {
            // increment values
            el_qty.val(--currentVal);
            el_bes.val(--bestandVal);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine - Many Thanks for your quick help - now it's runnig like it should...

Comment: Do you mean "useful"??? This was very - very - VERY USEFUL... and perfect to understand... Thank you again!

Comment: How can the script be updated if i like to zero all the other fields except the one i click: Like if i already have increased qty1 by 2(+)-clicks and now i change to qty2 starting to increase qty2 and in the same moment qty1 becomes zero and the value of qty1 will be added back to bestand1? Hope i could explain in english what i mean... Thanks for help..

Comment: I managed it now with some hidden fields and it runs quite well... guess the code is much to komplex but as long as it works it should be enough...

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of finding the corresponding **bestand** is wrong

```
$(this).next(".bestand")
```

The **bestand** is not the next sibling of the +/- button.

---

The HTML is a little different, hope it's ok...
Html:

```
<div class="container">
    bestand1
    <input type="text" id="bestand1" value="20" class="bestand" disabled />
    <br /><br />
    product1
    <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="add" />        
    <input type="text" id="qty1" value="2" class="qty" disabled/>        
    <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />
</div> 
<br /><br />
<div class="container">
    bestand2
    <input type="text" id="bestand2" value="20" class="bestand" disabled />
    <br /><br />
    product2
    <input type="button" value="+" id="add2" class="add" />        
    <input type="text" id="qty2" value="2" class="qty" disabled/>        
    <input type="button" value="-" id="minus2" class="minus" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    $(".add").click(function()
    {
        var container = $(this).closest(".container");
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.find(".qty").val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt(container.find(".bestand").val());
        if (currentVal >= 10)
        {
            container.find(".qty").val(currentVal = 10);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal < 10)
        {
            container.find(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
            container.find(".bestand").val(bestandVal - 1);
        }
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var container = $(this).closest(".container");
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.find(".qty").val());
        var bestandVal = parseInt(container.find(".bestand").val());

        if (currentVal <= 0)
        {
            container.find(".qty").val(currentVal = 0);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal > 0)
        {
            container.find(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
            container.find(".bestand").val(bestandVal + 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pCcBb/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this: **http://jsfiddle.net/2TJnJ/**

Here i am linking the fields with **class** to **id**.

```
$(function()
{
    $(".add").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).next(".qty").val());
        var getBestandID = "#"+$(this).parent().attr('class');
        var bestandVal = parseInt($(getBestandID).val());

        if (currentVal >= 10)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal = 10);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal < 10)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
            $(getBestandID).val(bestandVal - 1);
        }  
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".qty").val());
        var getBestandID = "#"+$(this).parent().attr('class');
        var bestandVal = parseInt($(getBestandID).val());

        if (currentVal <= 0)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal = 0);
        }
        if (currentVal != NaN && currentVal > 0)
        {
            $(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
            $(getBestandID).val(bestandVal + 1);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Try seeing the link.. I added a div container for the linking part :)